# In MonoDevelop, how do I set the application output to a fixed-width font?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I can't find any sort of font settings for Application Output. I'm not sure why it's not fixed-width by default. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it via Edit->Preferences->Visual Style

Check "Custom font for Output pads" and select the font you would like.

Comment: Yep, this is fixed in the latest version of MonoDevelop (2.4).

Answer (score 2):

MonoDevelop is still pretty much in development, there are quite a few features we would like to see.

You could report it as a feature request [here](http://mono-project.com/Bugs), or even better, contribute and propose a patch for it.